# Infinispan/JDBC as Backend for Hibernate Search on Wildfly/JBoss

Tags: jdbc, jboss, wildfly, hibernate-search, infinispan

I am trying to configure a JDBC-backed Infinispan cache to act as the backend for my Java EE app making use of Hibernate Search.  I am deploying on JBoss EAP 7.0 or Wildfly 10.  I have a module, cache container, and persistence.xml configuration that does not give me any errors on startup.  In addition, I am able to create JPA objects and have them indexed via Hibernate Search as expected.  I am then able to query those objects successfully.  However, at no time are the SQL tables created in the database that I have configured as my JDBC data source for the cache container.  So, obviously, the search indices only exist in memory and are not persisted across app server restarts.  Here is what I have done thus far:

1. Downloaded the Infinispan 8.1.x release that corresponds to the Infinispan release embedded within JBoss EAP.  This was done because the hibernate-search modules from Infinispan are not included in the embedded module
2. I've configured the appropriate modules for the Infinispan hibernate-search module within JBoss EAP
3. Modified my standalone-full-ha.xml JBoss EAP configuration file to include a JDBC-backed cache-container and cache definitions
4. Modified my persistence.xml file to make use of an Infinispan cache manager and directory provider

Here is the definition for my cache-container as found in standalone-full-ha.xml:

```
 <cache-container name="hibernateSearch" default-cache="LuceneIndexesData" module="org.infinispan.cachestore.jdbc" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/hibernateSearch">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesMetadata" statistics-enabled="true" mode="SYNC">
                <binary-keyed-jdbc-store data-source="InfinispanCacheDS" passivation="false" purge="false" shared="true">
                    <binary-keyed-table>
                        <id-column name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <data-column name="DATUM" type="BYTEA"/>
                    </binary-keyed-table>
                </binary-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </replicated-cache>
            <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesData" statistics-enabled="true" mode="SYNC">
                <binary-keyed-jdbc-store data-source="InfinispanCacheDS" passivation="false" purge="false" shared="true">
                    <binary-keyed-table>
                        <id-column name="ID_COLUMN" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <data-column name="DATUM" type="BYTEA"/>
                    </binary-keyed-table>
                </binary-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </replicated-cache>
            <replicated-cache name="LuceneIndexesLocking" statistics-enabled="true" mode="SYNC"/>
        </cache-container>
```

Here is my JDBC data source from standalone-full-ha.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/InfinispanCacheDS" pool-name="InfinispanCacheDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_infinispan_cache</connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql-jdbc4</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>infinispan_cache</user-name>
                    <password>mypassword</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <track-statements>true</track-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/datasources/MyDataSourceDS</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                value="java:/MyDataSourceEntityManagerFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto" />

            <!-- Transactions -->
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />

            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5" />

            <!-- Caching support - Infinispan -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager"
                value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="true" />

            <!-- Hibernate Search properties - Generic -->
            <property name="hibernate.search.reader.strategy" value="shared" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.worker.execution" value="sync" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.jmx_enabled" value="true" />

            <!-- Hibernate Search properties - Infinispan -->
            <property name="hibernate.search.infinispan.cachemanager_jndiname"
                value="java:jboss/infinispan/hibernateSearch" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                value="infinispan" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.infinispan.chunk_size"
                value="300000000" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When JBoss starts up, I do not see any errors.  I also don't see any reference to JDBC, however.  I also do not see any errors when persisting JPA objects, so it seems they are being indexed appropriately.  It's just that my Hibernate Search index isn't being saved in the database as I would expect.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, the Infinispan extensions used by Hibernate Search for this purpose are not included within the Infinispan module which is part of WildFly / JBoss EAP, so you correctly downloaded the Infinispan modules from the Infinispan project.

What you are missing is that WildFly is able to isolate modules very effectively, so the first thing you have to realise is that you really don't have to match the version of Infinispan as included in WildFly.

Since you will be using the module set from infinispan.org, you should NOT configure these caches in your JBoss EAP configuration file, as the caches defined there are controlled by the clustering subsystem and will affect the cache definitions created by the Infinispan modules included in WildFly (the Infinispan modules at slot "main").

You should include an Infinispan configuration file in your Hibernate Search based application, and have it start a new CacheManager using the right module.

Alternatively you can create another application to start the CacheManager in any way you like - as long as you depend on the right Infinispan modules (avoid the "main" slot) - then register it to JNDI and have Hibernate Search look for that name.

N.B. the Hibernate Search module has a dependency to the *optional* Infinispan module, so it will attempt to load the right Infinispan module if it's present:

https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/84d88b8/feature-pack/src/main/resources/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/search/engine/main/module.xml#L53

Be aware also that thanks to the module system, you can override / upgrade the Hibernate Search version.
In terms of versions your restrictions are :

- pick an Infinispan module version compatible with your Hibernate Search version of choice
- pick an Hibernate Search version compatible with the Hibernate ORM version of choice

(That's right, [you can override / upgrade Hibernate ORM as well](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html)).

Assuming you are using the default version of Hibernate ORM and Hibernate Search as included in WildFly 10, you could download the Infinispan modules at version 8.2.6.Final (the latest stable release) as it also contains a module

```
<module name="org.infinispan.hibernate-search.directory-provider" slot="for-hibernatesearch-5.5" >
```

Or if you're using JBoss EAP, you might prefer to download the JBoss Data Grid distribution, which will contain the same features as the Infinispan modules.

Comment: I have Hibernate Search writing to the Inifnispan cache correctly (as best I can tell).  There are no index files created on disk.  And when I perform a Hibernate Search query the results come back as expected.  So, it appears to me as though the data *is* being stored in Infinispan, it's just *not* being persisted in my SQL database the way I expected.  So it seems to me that there is an issue with my cache-container definition that is causing it not to use the JDBC cache store.  I just can't figure out what, specifically, is the problem.

Comment: I should also mention that I'm not using the full Infinispan modules set from infinispan.org.  I'm only creating modules for the JAR files that are not included in the Wildfly Infinispan module set.  Additionally, I'm not embedding Hibernate/Hibernate search in my WAR file.  I'm using the modules provided by Wildfly there too.

Comment: You should either have the right tables in the PostgreSQL database, or we should see an error. I'm not sure which one, but either it's not actually using the Infinispan DirectoryProvider, or we're missing to see the errors. I presume you checked the logs? Indexing operations happen in a different thread, so your main application might not notice. You need to either check the logs or configure an alternative ErrorHandler: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#exception-handling